# C++ под Win64

Tags: winapi, ide, c++

Здравствуйте! Не подскажите среду разработки С++ под Win64?) Спасибо)

Comment: Уроки разработки 64-битных приложений на языке Си/Си++ - http://www.viva64.com/ru/l/ - курс посвящен созданию 64-битных приложений на языке Си/Си++ и ориентирован на разработчиков Windows-приложений, использующих среду Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code::Blocks, Visual Studio и другие, особой разницы нету между Win32 и Win64 нету для среды разработки :-) А если вы хотите писать под Win64 то это в настройках компилятора надо покапаться

Comment: Дело в том, что  Borland 4.5 C++ на Windows 7 64x не ставится...

Comment: Попробуйте поставить виртуальную машину с XP а на неё C++ Builder. На работе Win7 так в ней самой не получается работать с Delphi 5, поэтому использую VirtualBox c Windows XP.

Comment: На Win7 Delphi 7 хорошо работает, с совместимостью с XP SP2 (у меня сейчас стоит)... Но у меня 32-разрядная, и Borland  С++ 4.5 хорошо работает, а вот на другой машине, где 64, он ставиться не хоч... Про виртуальную машину я знаю, но все таки хотелось без неё как нить обойтись...

Comment: А чем вас пугает виртуальная машина, очень кстати удобная вещь, что VMWARE что VirtualBox. Бесплатны, функциональны, практически разницы в использование не заметите, использую на intel core 2 с 2 гб памяти. Всегда можно скопировать всю систему и использовать на другой машине

Comment: Да не, я ничего против не имею;) Можно попробовать) В принципе я так и сделаю, но для начала Visual Studio испробую, а то еще не сталкивался с ним, хотя не однократно слышал;) Спасибо)

Comment: Только не начинайте ругать Visual Studio за убогость, его отлично дополняет Visual Assist. :-)

Comment: Ок;)Хорошо что предупредили;) хехе)

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio наверное)